# r Error dim(X) must have a positive length?

Tags: r

I want to compute the mean of "Population" of built-in matrix `state.x77`. The codes are :

```
apply(state.x77[,"Population"],2,FUN=mean)

#Error in apply(state.x77[, "Population"], 2, FUN = mean) : 

# dim(X) must have a positive length
```

how can I prevent this error? If I use `$` sign

```
apply(state.x77$Population,2,mean)
# Error in state.x77$Population : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

What is atomic vector?

Comment: But regardless, if you're just doing this for one column, why not just `mean(state.x77[,"Population"])`?

Comment: @joran Thank you very much . both the reference FAQs and  mean(state.x77[,"Population"]) are beneficial.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To expand on joran's comments, consider:

```
> is.vector(state.x77[,"Population"])
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(state.x77[,"Population"])
[1] FALSE
```

So, your `Population` data is now no diferent from any other vector, like `1:10`, which has neither columns or rows to `apply` against. It is just a series of numbers with no more advanced structure or dimension. E.g.

```
> apply(1:10,2,mean)
Error in apply(1:10, 2, mean) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Which means you can just use the `mean` function directly against the matrix subset which you have selected: E.g.:

```
> mean(1:10)
[1] 5.5
> mean(state.x77[,"Population"])
[1] 4246.42
```

---

To explain 'atomic' vector more, see the R FAQ again (and this gets a bit complex, so hold on to your hat)...

> R has six basic (‘atomic’) vector types: logical, integer, real,
>   complex, string (or character) and raw.
>   http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Vector-objects

So atomic in this instance is referring to vectors as the basic building blocks of R objects (like atoms make up everything in the real world).

If you read R's inline help by entering `?"$"` as a command, you will find it says:

> ‘$’ is only valid for recursive objects, and is only
>        discussed in the section below on recursive objects.

Since vectors (like `1:10`) are basic building blocks ("atomic"), with no recursive sub-elements, trying to use `$` to access parts of them will not work.

Since your matrix (`statex.77`) is essentially just a vector with some dimensions, like:

```
> str(matrix(1:10,nrow=2))
 int [1:2, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

...you also can't use `$` to access sub-parts.

```
> state.x77$Population
Error in state.x77$Population : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But you can access subparts using `[` and names like so:

```
> state.x77[,"Population"]
   Alabama         Alaska        Arizona...
      3615            365           2212...
```

Comment: how does this work on a similar data fir e.g.
`> is.vector(state.center$x)
[1] TRUE

> is.matrix(state.center$x)
[1] FALSE

> state.center$x
 [1]  -86.7509 -127.2500 -111.6250  -92.2992 -119.7730.......