# R: Applying a dprime function - apply() error 'dim(X) must have a positive length'

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to write a dprime function where I subtract FA from hits z-scores to get a dprime value for each participant. Participants are rows and z-scores are columns. My dataset (newData) is 18x16 but I want to ignore the first 8 columns. I want to repeat the dprime calculation for each of condition and create a new 18x4 dataset (newData2) with the output.

```
# Function to apply
dprimeFun <- function(twoColumns){
  # Give the function two columns at a time
  zH <- twoColumns[ 1 ]
  zF <- twoColumns[ 2 ]
  dprime <- zH - zF 
  return(dprime)
}

# Apply the function
newData2 <- cbind(
  # Condition 1 dprimes
  apply(
    newData[ c( "zH1","zF1" ) ], MARGIN=1, FUN=dprimeFun
  ),
  # Repeat for each condition
)
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
Error in apply(newData[c("zH1", "zF1")], MARGIN = 1, FUN = dprimeFun) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682576/r-error-dimx-must-have-a-positive-length) where somebody had the same error message, however I think their solution (just apply the function directly to the data subset) won't work for me because I'd have to do so 72 times.

I also read the R FAQ ['Why do matrices lose dimensions?'](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-my-matrices-lose-dimensions_003f) but I don't understand how it applies to my 18x16 dataset.

I'm an R newb so help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

```
# newData structure
> str(newData)
 num [1:18, 1:16] 0.833 0.833 0.833 0.833 0.833 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:16] "H1" "F1" "H2" "F2" ...

# newData column names
> colnames(newData)
 [1] "H1"  "F1"  "H2"  "F2"  "H3"  "F3"  "H4"  "F4"  "zH1" "zF1" "zH2" "zF2" "zH3" "zF3"
[15] "zH4" "zF4"
```

Comment: You're so far off it's hard to figure out where you want to go. Perhaps if you show a few rows of newData? Unless columns zH1 and zF1 are already z-scores this is not going to compute a dprime. All of your `cbind` and `apply` is completely pointless and wrong. Did you try just calling your function and passing it a two column `data.frame` as the argument? It really looks like you have thought a lot about things and read things but what you really need to do is try things and see what happens. Your computer won't blow up. And it's a far far better way to learn this stuff.

Comment: What happens when you type: `dim(newData[ c( "zH1","zF1" ) ])`?

Comment: @John Thank you for your comment. Columns zH1 zF1 are already z-scores. Here is a few rows from newData:

Comment: 0.9674216 1.0675705 0.9674216 -0.4307273

Comment: I tried what you said about passing it a two column data.frame (I gave it columns zH1 and zH2) and it came back with 0 as the answer. I'm not sure why 1) the answer is 0, and 2) why it is a single number rather than 18 numbers. 

To be honest I am just so new to R I really have no idea what I'm doing, the reason I used cbind and apply was because I got it to work for calculating hit rates so I thought it might work for the next stage too. I appreciate you taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: @jlhoward It comes back as NULL. I also tried dim() on my two column data.frame as John suggested, which came back 18x2. I'm not sure I understand why has one got dimensions and the other doesn't... If you could give me any guidance on what's going wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: OK. Type `str(newData)` and post the result, preferably as an edit to your question. My guess is that the column names are not what you think they are. If I type `newData<-data.frame(zH1=1:10,zF1=1:10); dim(newData); dim(newData[,c("zH1","zF1")])` I get the same answer (10,2) both times.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to include `str(newData)` and `colnames(newData)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want...

```
newData$dprime <- dprimeFun(newData[,c("zH1", "zF1")])
```

But it's extraordinarily hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following (it won't let me do newData$dprime because dprime isn't the name of anything in that dataframe): 

    `blah <- dprimeFun(newData[,c("zH1", "zF1")])` 

It created a list with two elements which were both 0. 

I am trying to calculate dprime from two columns, each with 18 rows, and repeat this 4 times for each two-column set (hits and FAs for each condition). I have no doubt my code is a mess, that's why I came here, and I am very new to R. If there's anything I can do to make the problem clearer please tell me. I've never asked a question on here before.