# Adding a new column to matrix error

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to add a new column to existing matrix, but getting warning everytime.

I'm trying this code:

```
normDisMatrix$newColumn <- labels
```

Getting this message:

> Warning message: In normDisMatrix$newColumn <- labels : Coercing LHS
>   to a list

After it, when I check the matrix, it seems null:

```
dim(normDisMatrix)
NULL
```

**Note:** labels are just vectors which have numbers between 1 and 4.

What can be the problem?

Comment: You can't use `$` to subset matrices - see the bottom part of my previous answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682576/r-error-dimx-must-have-a-positive-length/16682747#16682747

Comment: You might give us some data where we can reproduce the error. As is I have no clue what 'labels' is nor 'normDisMatrix' nor myMatrix

Comment: @thelatemai thank you for answer, can you suggest me a way to add a column to matrix.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out, the `$` operator cannot be used to subset a matrix.  This is because a matrix is just a single vector with a dimension attribute.  When you used `$` to try to add a new column, R converted your matrix to the lowest structure where `$` can be used on the vector, which is a list.

The function you want is `cbind()` (**c**olumn **bind**).  Suppose I have the matrix `m`

```
(m <- matrix(51:70, 4))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   51   55   59   63   67
# [2,]   52   56   60   64   68
# [3,]   53   57   61   65   69
# [4,]   54   58   62   66   70
```

To add the a new column from a vector called `labels`, we can do

```
labels <- 1:4
cbind(m, newColumn = labels)
#                     newColumn
# [1,] 51 55 59 63 67         1
# [2,] 52 56 60 64 68         2
# [3,] 53 57 61 65 69         3
# [4,] 54 58 62 66 70         4
```