# How to append a vector as a column in R matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, append

Suppose I have a matrix similar as the one show below in R.

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] 
[1,]    2    4    3 
[2,]    2    5    7
```

How can append a column to the front like below.

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1   2    4    3 
[2,] 1   1    5    7
```

Lastly, the matrix has many rows.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790970/5414452 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074399/adding-a-new-column-in-a-matrix-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a new column in a matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074399/adding-a-new-column-in-a-matrix-in-r)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `cbind`

```
cbind(c(1,2), matrix(1:6, nrow=2))
```

So in case you work with bigger data, imagine your matrix is saved as `m` and you have a vector `my_vector` you want to add as a column in front of this matrix, the command would be

```
new_m <- cbind(my_vector, m)
```

Make sure the dimension of your vector fit the number of rows in your matrix.

In case you want to add rows instead of columns, the command is called `rbind` and is used in exactly the same way.

Comment: My matrix has hundreds of rows. How can I change c(1,2) to account for this?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer your comment here as well.

Comment: just realised you were asking how to add in front... Updated my answer agin :-) And talking about the many rows, I guess you know how many rows and you have a vector fitting into your matrix... So just use this vector

Comment: @jojo the question explicitly states that the matrix has many rows