# Calculate cumulative product over 1 year time windows in R

Tags: r, xts, rollapply

I have problem requiring me to calculate the rolling product of a series of 1 period returns. The length of the rolling window is variable. The purpose is to obtain the rolling product of the 1 period returns that covers as closely as possible a 12 months window.

I have been able to produce a working solution using brute force through `for` loops and `if` statements, however I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution. I have spent a lot of time trying with `rollapply` and other similar functions but I haven't been able to obtain a solution.

The data below illustrates the problem.

```
    date        rt_1_period rt_12_mth_window
1   04-04-13    NA          NA
2   10-04-13    0.729096362 NA
3   24-05-13    1.002535647 NA
4   30-05-13    0.993675716 NA
5   21-07-13    1.002662843 NA
6   03-08-13    1.009516582 NA
7   01-09-13    0.963099395 NA
8   20-10-13    1.012470278 NA
9   25-10-13    1.01308502  NA
10  03-11-13    1.005440704 NA
11  01-01-14    1.024208021 NA
12  11-01-14    0.996613924 NA
13  17-02-14    1.009811368 NA
14  24-02-14    1.008139557 NA
15  30-03-14    1.002794709 NA
16  30-04-14    0.998745849 1.042345473
17  02-05-14    1.002324076 1.044767963
18  27-06-14    0.997741026 1.046389027
19  24-08-14    1.015767546 1.050072129
20  05-09-14    1.014405005 1.106010894
21  02-11-14    1.013830296 1.09319212
22  09-11-14    1.013127219 1.101549487
23  16-11-14    1.012614177 1.115444628
24  18-01-15    0.986893629 1.078458006
25  24-01-15    1.028120919 1.108785236
26  10-04-15    0.912452762 0.991025615
27  09-08-15    1.004676152 0.981376513
28  07-01-16    1.004236123 0.934086003
29  01-04-16    1.02341302  0.94215696
```

In the example the 12 months return for row 29 is calculated as the product of 1 period return from row 26 to 29 because 02-04-15 (365 days from 01-04-16) is contained between rows 25 and 26. On the other side the 12 months return for row 15 is NA because 30-03-13 (365 days from 30-03-14) is outside the time window for which I have observable 1 period returns.

I would be glad if somebody could suggest some way of approaching this problem.

Just for clarity, if the data provided do not make much sense is because this is a cut down version of a larger database that I have created for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xts` and `lubridate` for simplyfying date manipulations

**Data:**

```
require(xts)
require(lubridate)


DF = read.csv(text="
date,rt_1_period,rt_12_mth_window
04-04-13,           ,
10-04-13,0.729096362,
24-05-13,1.002535647,
30-05-13,0.993675716,
21-07-13,1.002662843,
03-08-13,1.009516582,
01-09-13,0.963099395,
20-10-13,1.012470278,
25-10-13,1.01308502 ,
03-11-13,1.005440704,
01-01-14,1.024208021,
11-01-14,0.996613924,
17-02-14,1.009811368,
24-02-14,1.008139557,
30-03-14,1.002794709,
30-04-14,0.998745849,1.042345473
02-05-14,1.002324076,1.044767963
27-06-14,0.997741026,1.046389027
24-08-14,1.015767546,1.050072129
05-09-14,1.014405005,1.106010894
02-11-14,1.013830296,1.09319212
09-11-14,1.013127219,1.101549487
16-11-14,1.012614177,1.115444628
18-01-15,0.986893629,1.078458006
24-01-15,1.028120919,1.108785236
10-04-15,0.912452762,0.991025615
09-08-15,1.004676152,0.981376513
07-01-16,1.004236123,0.934086003
01-04-16,1.02341302 ,0.94215696",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings="")


#Convert to xts time series for ease in date manipulation

DF_xts = xts(DF[,-1],order.by = as.Date(DF[,1],format="%d-%m-%y"))
head(DF_xts)
#   
#              rt_1_period rt_12_mth_window
#2013-04-04          NA               NA
#2013-04-10 0.729096362               NA
#2013-05-24 1.002535647               NA
#2013-05-30 0.993675716               NA
#2013-07-21 1.002662843               NA
#2013-08-03 1.009516582               NA




#set lag period as 1 year
lagPeriod = 1
```

**Cumulative 12m Product:**

For each date construct a window [prevYearDate,date], subset 1m returns lying in this window, calculate cumulative product and select last product

```
rt_12_mth_window_Calc = do.call(rbind,lapply(as.Date(index(DF_xts)),function(x) {

prevYearDate = x-years(lagPeriod)

rt_12_mth_window_Calc = last(cumprod(DF_xts[paste0(prevYearDate,"/",x),"rt_1_period"]))
colnames(rt_12_mth_window_Calc) = "rt_12_mth_window_Calc"

return(rt_12_mth_window_Calc)

}))
```

**Final Dataset:**

```
#Merge with original time series for final dataset

new_DF = merge.xts(DF_xts,rt_12_mth_window_Calc)

#Calculate difference in original and calculated 12 month returns
new_DF$delta = new_DF$rt_12_mth_window_Calc - new_DF$rt_12_mth_window
new_DF

#           rt_1_period rt_12_mth_window rt_12_mth_window_Calc           delta
#2013-04-04          NA               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-04-10 0.729096362               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-05-24 1.002535647               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-05-30 0.993675716               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-07-21 1.002662843               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-08-03 1.009516582               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-09-01 0.963099395               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-10-20 1.012470278               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-10-25 1.013085020               NA                    NA              NA
#2013-11-03 1.005440704               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-01-01 1.024208021               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-01-11 0.996613924               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-02-17 1.009811368               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-02-24 1.008139557               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-03-30 1.002794709               NA                    NA              NA
#2014-04-30 0.998745849      1.042345473           1.042345470 -2.64001643e-09
#2014-05-02 1.002324076      1.044767963           1.044767960 -2.54864396e-09
#2014-06-27 0.997741026      1.046389027           1.046389025 -1.97754613e-09
#2014-08-24 1.015767546      1.050072129           1.050072127 -1.66086833e-09
#2014-09-05 1.014405005      1.106010894           1.106010893 -1.34046041e-09
#2014-11-02 1.013830296      1.093192120           1.093192120 -6.47777387e-11
#2014-11-09 1.013127219      1.101549487           1.101549488  5.99306826e-10
#2014-11-16 1.012614177      1.115444628           1.115444628 -1.89856353e-10
#2015-01-18 0.986893629      1.078458006           1.078458005 -1.15637744e-09
#2015-01-24 1.028120919      1.108785236           1.108785235 -9.57268265e-10
#2015-04-10 0.912452762      0.991025615           0.991025613 -1.54581248e-09
#2015-08-09 1.004676152      0.981376513           0.996850412  1.54738992e-02
#2016-01-07 1.004236123      0.934086003           0.934086002 -9.15302278e-10
#2016-04-01 1.023413020      0.942156960           0.942156960 -1.82048598e-10
```

The calculated and orignal values are very close for all observations except for
2015-08-09, the deviation in values is 1.55%, could you confirm your calculations for this period

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Much appreciated! You are right on the 2015-08-09. The data I have used were a copy paste from a mock up Excel spreadsheet and your version is correct. I have started using your code and seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried to run the code on the real dataset which is an expnded version of what I have posted and got the following error
`Error in apply(coredata(x), 2, function(y) cumprod(y)) :
 dim(X) must have a positive length`
Do you know what could be origin? Thanks in advance

Comment: could you update your question and include the function call you are doing along with `dput(head(data))` wherre `data` is your input data. Only then we can replicate the error

Comment: I tried the snippet you posted and it ran fine with one change, replacing `rt_1_mth` by `rt_1_period`,  check out the link for atomic vectors and apply [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682576/r-error-dimx-must-have-a-positive-length)

Comment: You are correct! Apologize for the silly mistake, it works as intended. Will remove the edit on the question since is irrelevant. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that only depends on xts, and it might be more straight-forward to some.

```
library(xts)
x <- as.xts(read.zoo(text="date,rt_1_period,rt_12_mth_window
04-04-13,           ,
10-04-13,0.729096362,
24-05-13,1.002535647,
30-05-13,0.993675716,
21-07-13,1.002662843,
03-08-13,1.009516582,
01-09-13,0.963099395,
20-10-13,1.012470278,
25-10-13,1.013085020,
03-11-13,1.005440704,
01-01-14,1.024208021,
11-01-14,0.996613924,
17-02-14,1.009811368,
24-02-14,1.008139557,
30-03-14,1.002794709,
30-04-14,0.998745849,1.042345473
02-05-14,1.002324076,1.044767963
27-06-14,0.997741026,1.046389027
24-08-14,1.015767546,1.050072129
05-09-14,1.014405005,1.106010894
02-11-14,1.013830296,1.09319212
09-11-14,1.013127219,1.101549487
16-11-14,1.012614177,1.115444628
18-01-15,0.986893629,1.078458006
24-01-15,1.028120919,1.108785236
10-04-15,0.912452762,0.991025615
09-08-15,1.004676152,0.981376513
07-01-16,1.004236123,0.934086003
01-04-16,1.023413020,0.94215696", header=TRUE, sep=",", format="%d-%m-%y"))
ix <- index(x)       # index values
ixlag <- ix-365      # 1-year lag index values
x$rt_12 <- NA_real_  # initialize result column
for(i in which(ixlag > ix[1])) {
   # 1-year subset
   xyear <- window(x, start=ixlag[i], end=ix[i])
   # calculate product and update result column
   x[i,"rt_12"] <- prod(xyear[,"rt_1_period"])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution!